# Angular 2 issue with async tests

Tags: angular, jasmine, angular2-testing

I have the following method in a component:

```
onSignup() {
    if (this.form.valid) {
      let email = this.form.value.email;
      let password = this.form.value.password;
      this.usersService.signup(email, password)
        .then(() => {
          this.router.navigate(['/app/recipes']);
        })
        .catch(err => {
          console.log('2')
          this.mdlSnackbarService.showToast(err);
        });
    }
  }
```

And the following unit test:

```
it('#onSignup should show error on error', async(() => {
    spyOn(fixture.debugElement.injector.get(UsersService), 'signup')
      .and.returnValue(Promise.reject('some error'));

    component.form.setValue({'email': 'mail@mail.com', 'password': '123456'});

    console.log('1')
    component.onSignup();

    fixture.whenStable().then(() => {
      console.log('3')
      expect(snackbar.showToast).toHaveBeenCalled();
    })
  }));
```

I have mocked the snackBarService with:

```
snackbar = { showToast: jasmine.createSpy('showToast').and.callFake((str)=>console.log(str)) };
```

Checking the output, I can see how the mock is properly called, although, something is not quite right with the synchronization:

```
LOG: '1'
Chrome 56.0.2924 (Mac OS X 10.10.5): Executed 0 of 7 SUCCESS (0 secs / 0 secs)
LOG: '3'
Chrome 56.0.2924 (Mac OS X 10.10.5): Executed 0 of 7 SUCCESS (0 secs / 0 secs)
LOG: '2'
Chrome 56.0.2924 (Mac OS X 10.10.5): Executed 0 of 7 SUCCESS (0 secs / 0 secs)
LOG: 'some error'
```

It seems like the check for the method to been called is executed before it is called. Then it fails with `Expected spy showToast to have been called.`.

Can anyone point out what I am doing wrong here?